# Como fazer um return de um Stored Procedure - MySQL

Tags: mysql, login, stored-procedures

Estou fazendo uma  tela de login, porem não consigo retornar o ID do usuario selecionado.

```
DELIMITER $$
USE  webnote $$
CREATE PROCEDURE login (IN email2 varchar(60), senha2 varchar(16))
    BEGIN
        if EXISTS(select id_aluno from aluno where email = email2 and senha = senha2)
        then
             select id_aluno from aluno;
        else
            select "Erro ao efetuar login!!"; 
        end if;
    END$$

DELIMITER ;

call login('tester.develop@arrouba.com', '1234');

select @return;
```